# Eclipse Android project type vanished

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm using Ubuntu Oneiric.

I started my first Android project in Eclipse, and after the initial development went well, I installed the Egit plugin into Eclipse (it took running Eclipse with sudo).

Now the Android project type seems to have vanished, my existing Android project has become a "Java" project, so I can't run it in the virtual Android device any more.

I can't reinstall the plugin, because I get an error saying it's already installed when I try.

Any ideas how I can proceed?

Comment: You shouldn't be running Eclipse with sudo, I'm sure its related somehow

Comment: Thanks, I agree. Unfortunately, I had to run it with sudo to be able to install the git plugin - otherwise the add software dialog stays empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed Eclipse, and reinstalled using apt-get.

I hadn't deleted my workspace, so when I opened Eclipse again, it had remembered all my settings, and the Android project was open, *as* an Android project. The Git plugin was working too!

It's not quite "have you tried turning it off and on again" but it's close.